# Railsで使用されている=（イコール）の記号の使い方について教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails初心者ですが下記のようなviewファイルがあり、
ソースコードのis_selected = @registration.plan == planの記号で困惑してます。

これはまず右辺を@registration.planとplanが等しいかどうか計算して、
値が等しい場合の左辺のis_selectedに代入するというような意味合いでしょうか？

ちなみに=の記号が代入、==の記号が等しいと認識しております。

viewファイル

```
<% is_selected = @registration.plan == plan %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

結論から言うと `is_selected` には `true` か `false` のいづれかの値が入ります。
等しければ true、異なれば false です。
先の人も書いていますが優先順位があるので

```
is_selected = (@registration.plan == plan)
```

と同じだと考えれば分かりやすいと思います。

最終的には is_selected を求めているので、これは名前からしても
「選択されているのか?否か?」を保持したいのだと思います。

例えばそのソースコードの後の方で

```rb
if is_selected
  # ...選択されている場合の処理
end
```

と書いてもいいですし、変数を使わずに

```rb
if @registration.plan == plan
  # ...選択されている場合の処理
end
```

と書いても同じ意味になります。

参考: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/class/Object.html#I_--3D--3D

Answer (score 1):

> これはまず右辺を@registration.planとplanが等しいかどうか計算して、値が等しい場合の左辺のis_selectedに代入するというような意味合いでしょうか？

左辺、右辺と考えるとややこしいです。優先順位の高いところから結合します。質問の式では=より==の方が優先順位が高いのでそこから結合します。

冗長に書くと

```
is_selected = ( @registration.plan == plan )
```

こうです。もし仮に=の方が優先順位が高ければ

```
（ is_selected = @registration.plan ) == plan
```

こうなります。